# Enter Ubuntu's VPN's credentials using CLI only, avoiding GUI

Tags: ubuntu, networking, scripting, vpn

I spent days searching for a method to automate the process of logging in to Ubuntu's built-in VPN "Multi-protocol VPN Client (openconnect)", but I didn't find a way to do it, this is what I do using to log in using the GUI:

1. Expand "VPN Off" then press "Connect".

   [image]
2. Input a password then press the "Login" Button.

   [image]
3. Enter my email and password then press "Login" button.

   [image]
4. Enter the validation code then press "Login" button

   [image]

I tried variations of the following command but had no luck.

```
nmcli connection up id "$VPN_NAME" password-flags 1 username "$VPN_USERNAME" password "$VPN_PASSWORD"
```

Comment: Does this maybe help? https://askubuntu.com/questions/229800/how-to-auto-start-openvpn-client-on-ubuntu-cli

Comment: @Peregrino69 Thanks, but it didn't help, it doesn't show how to automate multiple steps authentication (PEM pass then username/PASSCODE then Response)